# Variations in Ubuntu 12.04 /usr/bin/time statistics

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, time

I have a command line tool which I run on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. I need to calculate the cpu time for this program. I have been checking /usr/bin/time function.

command:    `/usr/bin/time -v -a -o timelog.dat command args`

I run the same command on the same hardware for twice. The results from 2 runs are below:

1st run:

```
User time (seconds): 4085.50
System time (seconds): 4.75
Percent of CPU this job got: 54%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 2:04:19
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 5093280
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 384474
Voluntary context switches: 436
Involuntary context switches: 628160
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 24
File system outputs: 102936
```

2nd run:

```
User time (seconds): 2694.91
System time (seconds): 2.51
Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 45:18.91
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 5093280
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 384483
Voluntary context switches: 223
Involuntary context switches: 4321
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 9288
File system outputs: 100136
```

Specs of the server CPU: `Clock speed: 2.4 GHz, Turbo Speed: 2.7 GHz, 8 physical cores, 16 threads`

So, in the first run the server was on full load, I had more than 16 processes. In the second run I had 7 processes. How can I be sure about the timing information I get ? Can we make a comparison between these 2 runs when the CPU usage percentage is 99% on both ? Is there another method of measuring the exact time spent for a process ? Why do I get totally different results even though `/usr/bin/time` function should calculate CPU time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance,
Serhat